# How do I find value of M and N in array[M][N]?

Tags: assembly, x86

Consider the source code below, where M and N are constants declared with

```
#define 
int array1[M][N];
int array2[N][M];

void copy(int i, int j)
{
    array1[i][j] = array2[j][i];
}
```

Suppose the above code generates the following assembly code:

```
copy:
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp,%ebp
  pushl %ebx
  movl 8(%ebp),%ecx
  movl 12(%ebp),%eax
  leal 0(,%eax,4),%ebx
  leal 0(,%ecx,8),%edx
  subl %ecx,%edx
  addl %ebx,%eax
  sall $2,%eax
  movl array2(%eax,%ecx,4),%eax
  movl %eax,array1(%ebx,%edx,4)
  popl %ebx
  movl %ebp,%esp
  popl %ebp
  ret
```

What are the values of M and N?

Comment: Although someone was kind enough to do your homework (or exam question) for you please read this: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) . Asking this question with no attempt at a solution so that we can do your work for you is not what SO is about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is a homework (exam question) related problem with absolutely no effort shown

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, however

1. I didn't want to decrease the chances of anyone bothering to answer my question by obscuring it with my own thoughts and attempts over the past 2-3 hours. However I did only come here after adequately failing myself, having made some progress towards understanding. 

2. I'm not getting credit for this problem, however I am using it to study for an upcoming exam.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the link? And did you notice I mentioned an exam question. Either way this site is not a service to do homework and exam problems. You need to show some effort. You learn less by us handing you a solution to you on  plate. In the days before the internet (and SO) we might have gone to or professor and TA with questions, or formed study/peer groups where small groups of us would get together and work through problems with the intent that everyone would learn something.

Comment: I've read the link. Like I said before, I didn't want to obscure the question by showing the work I already did. I fully appreciate the fact that the policy is that we show our own effort when asking such questions. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let me write the assembly code like C.

```
void copy(int i, int j)
{
    int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    ecx = i;                                      /* movl 8(%ebp),%ecx */
    eax = j;                                      /* movl 12(%ebp),%eax */
    ebx = eax * 4;                                /* leal 0(,%eax,4),%ebx */
    edx = ecx * 8;                                /* leal 0(,%ecx,8),%edx */
    edx -= ecx;                                   /* subl %ecx,%edx */
    eax += ebx;                                   /* addl %ebx,%eax */
    eax <<= 2;                                    /* sall $2,%eax */
    eax = *(int*)((char*)array2 + eax + ecx * 4); /* movl array2(%eax,%ecx,4),%eax */
    *(int*)((char*)array1 + ebx + edx * 4) = eax; /* movl %eax,array1(%ebx,%edx,4) */
}
```

Then, merge some expressions.

```
void copy(int i, int j)
{
    int eax, edx;
    eax = (j + j * 4) * 4;
    edx = i * 8 - i;
    *(int*)((char*)array1 + (4 * j) + edx * 4) = *(int*)((char*)array2 + eax + i * 4);
}
```

Merge more expressions.

```
void copy(int i, int j)
{
    *(int*)((char*)array1 + (4 * j) + (4 * 7 * i)) = *(int*)((char*)array2 + (4 * i) + (4 * 5 * j));
}
```

The type of `array1[0]` is `int[N]`, and the type of `array2[0]` is `int[M]`.

The assembly code copies 4 bytes as `array1[i][j]` and `array2[j][i]`, so `int` should be 4 bytes in this environment.

From the coefficient, I can see that `array2[0]` is `4 * 5` bytes long and `array1[0]` is `4 * 7` bytes long.

The size of `array2[0]`, which is size of `int[M]` is `M` times the size of`int`, so `M` should be 5.

For the same reason, `N` should be 7.

Comment: You have provided a very nice answer, and normally I would upvote something like this. You simply answered a homework (exam) puzzle where the author basically asked `Do the work for me`. The downvote is because we are encouraging help vampires on SO by doing this.If the person asking the question would have shown some effort in finding a solution, and presented that in the question then I would be thinking about this differently